# Android: How to Force reload activity if came from background?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I need to force reload activity if something came from background. Meaning, it is already running and is called back from the list of active apps or is tapped on her icon.

I would like to ask what is best practice for this? Should I call `onCreate` again in `onResume` event or something else?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Move your code that you want to run every time your `Activity` comes to the foreground from `onCreate` to `onResume`. You don't have to worry about the code running the first time the `Activity` is launched because `onResume` is always called after `onCreate`. This diagram of the `Activity` lifecycle could help you understand this :

[image: lifecycle diagram]